# How to prove Binomial Theorem

Tags: binomial-theorem

[image]    [image: enter preformatted text here]

I have got through part a) and b) 
The answer is 365 and 364, respectively , however I'm not able to tackle part c)

Comment: Is that because you don't know what the Binomial Theorem is?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
A-B&=2^{2n}\binom{2n}0-2^{2n-1}\binom{2n}1+2^{2n-2}\binom{2n}2-2^{2n-3}\binom{2n}3+\cdots-2\binom{2n}{2n-1}+\binom{2n}{2n}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}
\binom{2n}k(-1)^k2^{2n-k}.
\end{align}
The binomial theorem states that
$$(x+y)^m=\sum_{k=0}^m \binom mkx^{m-k}y^k.$$
Does that look useful?

I think you should also work out $A+B$.